# how to check all check boxes which shown throgh for loop?

Tags: php, checkbox

I want to check all the check boxes which are in div tag
My code is as below.

```
<div id="cBoxes">
<li><input class="radio" name="list" id="list" type="checkbox" 
     value="<?php echo $resultPages['id'];?>"></li>
</div>
```

I have put this whole code in for loop with php tag.
Is there any way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Are you wanting to add something that will check all of them when the user clicks it, or have some selected based on previous user input, or do you really just mean you need to add `checked` to the code?

Comment: I believe that's invalid markup; the `<li>`'s need to be in a `<ol>` or a `<ul>` to be valid. Also, both answers (so far) are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `checked` attribute of `checkbox`. [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-checked) has complete documentation.

Answer (score 2):

See the `checked` attribute:

```
<div id="cBoxes">
<ul>
<li><input class="radio" name="list" id="list" type="checkbox" 
     value="<?php echo $resultPages['id'];?>" checked="checked"/></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Only quibble: Correct the lack of a `<ol>` or `<ul>` in the markup.